# Dialog box unresponsive with Windows Script Host (Python)

Tags: python, wsh

I am trying to modify the Print Setup option found under `File > Print Setup.`

I am using Windows Script Host with Python. I use the `Alt + F` followed by `S` to open the appropriate dialogue box:

[image: Print Setup]

When I do those commands by hand, the Print Setup box is in focus, so I can press `F` to select "Print to File" then `{ENTER}` or `O` to accept the changes.

However, I neither `ALT+F` nor `F` is selecting the File option.

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate('Point of Sale')
shell.SendKeys("%fs") # I also tried "%fsf and "%fs%f" removing the other call to SendKeys"
time.sleep(0.1) # Removing this (or using a longer wait) makes no difference
shell.SendKeys("F")
```

Comment: What if you send `%f`, wait, and send `s`? Is the S or ALT + F case sensitive? (i.e. does it matter if shift is pressed?)

Comment: @NickODell Inserting a wait in between the `%f` and `s`, doesn't execute the s command. These commands aren't case-sensitive; they work either way.

Comment: No, this is a python script.

Comment: What application is "Point of Sale"?

Comment: @ATOzTOA It's a software we use with out electronic cash registers. I don't think this issue is software specific, but it's just strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had to do with incorrect implementing on part of the developer of this software. To solve the problem, I used SendKeys to send multiple `TABS` until `File` was selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the dialog to appear before sending "F".

Try this:

```
shell.SendKeys("%fs")
time.sleep(.25)
shell.SendKeys("f")
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but unfortunately I tried this an it doesnt. Perhaps I need a way of getting the child ``Print Setup`` window in focus, even though when I run the keyboard shortcuts by hand, it is in focus.

Comment: Then the issue should be with `shell.AppActivate('Point of Sale')`, try `Notepad`.

Comment: The ``AppActivate`` simply brings the window into focus. I don't think that is the source of the error. With Notepad I can do several operations in one string ``shell.SendKeys("%fs%fMargins")``

Comment: Is the window being brought into focus when you run the script?

Comment: Yes it is; good point. But this just makes this error even stranger.

Comment: Can you try each key in separate `SendKeys`?